# .cshrc got empitied, aliases are loaded in opened terminal, how to retrieve them?

Tags: terminal, command-line, unix, alias

accidentally my `.cshrc` file got deleted, which had many aliases. I have terminal tab opened in my linux machine, which has all these aliases loaded in it. How can i retrieve it so that i could write them back to `.cshrc` file and get it back?

Answer (score 1):

From the manual, it seems that `alias` should list all of the aliases in the currently running shell:

> alias [name [wordlist]]
>
> Without arguments, prints all aliases.  With name, prints the
>   alias for name.  With name and wordlist, assigns wordlist as
>   the alias of name.  wordlist is command and filename
>   substituted.  name may not be `alias' or`unalias'.  See also
>   the unalias builtin command.